# BufferGeometry faces materials

Tags: javascript, three.js, buffer-geometry

When using BufferGeometry, how can I assign a material to a face ?

Is there something like an array containing the same informations that `Face#materialIndex` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BufferGeometry` doesn't support `MeshFaceMaterial`.

Comment: How can this functionality be replaced ? With multiple meshs ?

Comment: Yes. Internally multiple meshes get created when using MeshFaceMaterial anyway.